# Add Documentation suggestions when users ask new questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I thinking it might be a good idea to add Documentation suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/documentation to show up as the user begins to type in a question on Stack Overflow.

Currently we show a user common/similar questions that relate the keywords in their question but we do not show relative documentation. For example:

[image: Questions tat may already have your answer example]

I believe this would do the following:

- Reduce common programming questions by presenting reading material beforehand
- Drive new and existing users to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation

Comment: I would make sure that the Documentation links are marked as such, but it seems like a good suggestion for when Documentation gets out of beta.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Great distinction, this would be a good idea in order to separate documentation from previous questions/answers.